# Run a Batch as Administrator

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want a batch file what runs as administrator, now I found the following:

```
:: ### START UAC SCRIPT ###

if "%2"=="firstrun" exit
cmd /c "%0" null firstrun

if "%1"=="skipuac" goto skipuacstart

:checkPrivileges
NET FILE 1>NUL 2>NUL
if '%errorlevel%' == '0' ( goto gotPrivileges ) else ( goto getPrivileges )

:getPrivileges
if '%1'=='ELEV' (shift & goto gotPrivileges)

setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "batchPath=%~0"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
ECHO Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs"
ECHO UAC.ShellExecute "!batchPath!", "ELEV", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs"
"%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs"
exit /B

:gotPrivileges

setlocal & pushd .

cd /d %~dp0
cmd /c "%0" skipuac firstrun
cd /d %~dp0

:skipuacstart

if "%2"=="firstrun" exit

:: ### END UAC SCRIPT ###

:: ### START OF YOUR OWN BATCH SCRIPT BELOW THIS LINE ###
```

The problem is, I get a lot of errors in the command prompt, this is what I get:

> C:\Users\Mark\Desktop>if "firstrun" == "firstrun" exit
>
> C:\Users\Mark\Desktop>if "" == "skipuac" goto skipuacstart
>
> C:\Users\Mark\Desktop>NET FILE  1>NUL 2>NUL
>
> C:\Users\Mark\Desktop>if '2' == '0' (goto gotPrivileges  )  else (goto
>   getPrivil eges  )
>
> C:\Users\Mark\Desktop>if '' == 'ELEV' (shift   & goto gotPrivileges )
>
> C:\Users\Mark\Desktop>setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
>
> C:\Users\Mark\Desktop>set
>   "batchPath=C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\Testing.bat"
>
> C:\Users\Mark\Desktop>setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
>
> C:\Users\Mark\Desktop>ECHO Set UAC = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
>   1>"C:\Us ers\Mark\AppData\Local\Temp\OEgetPrivileges.vbs"
>
> C:\Users\Mark\Desktop>ECHO UAC.ShellExecute "!batchPath!", "ELEV", "",
>   "runas", 1  1>>"C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Temp\OEgetPrivileges.vbs"
>
> C:\Users\Mark\Desktop>"C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Temp\OEgetPrivileges.vbs"

Is there a way to fix this and just check for admin rights and ask for it there aren't?

Comment: Yeah, stick `@echo off` at the top of your script.

Comment: Those aren't errors.  Those are the commands that you're running.

Comment: It's very new for me working with Batch so I didn't know, Thanks @rojo for that advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting @echo off on the first line was the solution.

```
    @echo off 
:: ### START UAC SCRIPT ###

if "%2"=="firstrun" exit
cmd /c "%0" null firstrun

if "%1"=="skipuac" goto skipuacstart

:checkPrivileges
NET FILE 1>NUL 2>NUL
if '%errorlevel%' == '0' ( goto gotPrivileges ) else ( goto getPrivileges )

:getPrivileges
if '%1'=='ELEV' (shift & goto gotPrivileges)

setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "batchPath=%~0"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
ECHO Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs"
ECHO UAC.ShellExecute "!batchPath!", "ELEV", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs"
"%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs"
exit /B

:gotPrivileges

setlocal & pushd .

cd /d %~dp0
cmd /c "%0" skipuac firstrun
cd /d %~dp0

:skipuacstart

if "%2"=="firstrun" exit

:: ### END UAC SCRIPT ###

:: ### START OF YOUR OWN BATCH SCRIPT BELOW THIS LINE ###
```